# How to detect which html browser is opened and pop up there

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am facing is in the scenario that one opens my site in a browser and eventually on clicking a link through ***open.window()*** method another window of the same domain is opened. Probability of user staying in both the windows are equal. Now I want to detect which window the user is in and throw a javascript popup there. Though the code must be in the parent window. I have tried ***window.opener()*** method but it is of no help. Please help.

I have edited a lot and put it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2wBK/) for demo.

```
setInterval((function(){
$("div.mask").css("display","");
}),10000);

$("div.mask,div.close").click(function(event) {
var $target = $(event.target);

if ($target.hasClass("mask") == true
    || $target.hasClass("close") == true) {
    $("div.mask").css("display","none");
};
});
```

Now I want the masked popup to come at the top of all windows opened. Can we add .focus() to popup in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can know where the user "stays in". Better call your popup function in both windows. Just call your function and the popup will be opened where from it was called.
Anyway, I don't understand very well why you need to know which window the user is facing and what will open the popup.

Comment: I need to know which window the user is in because all other windows can be minimised at that time. More to that I cannot throw a popup in both as the popup functions as logout if not answered. More to that the popup is not triggered on any click, it is on DOM ready. Hope you got my handicaps here.

Comment: May be you can use a variable with the window reference in your "main window", then capture in each window you open the onfocus event and keep track on the "faced window". So when you need the popup, just open it in the window stored in your variable.

Comment: need something like window.focus(). But instead of window I need it in pop up.The following bit of code works perfectly. But I need a pop up.                                                     `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup() {
 newwindow=window.open('www.google.com','name','height=200,width=150');
 if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
 return false;
}
popitup();
setInterval ( popitup, 10000 );
// -->
</script>`